# NgFor Issue in expanding data in Accordion

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, accordion, ngfor

I have been trying to display an array of posts using tailwind's Accordion. When I console log the posts, the array of posts is there but there seems to be an issue of expanding the accordion. This only happens with dynamic data, when I tested with a hardcoded array, it works fine. With dynamic data it's showing the comment of "bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"}".

For creating a post and returning the array of posts, I am using a service, whenever a new post gets pushed, I will emit the new array of posts where the template will then subscribe to it. What am I doing wrong, please help a lost soul..

post-create.component.ts:

```
export class PostCreateComponent {

  constructor(public postService: PostService){}

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if(form.invalid){
      return;
    }
    this.postService.addPost(form.value.title, form.value.content);
    form.reset();
  }
}
```

post-service.ts:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PostService {
  posts: Post[] = [];
  updatePosts = new Subject<Post[]>()

  getPosts() {
    return [...this.posts];
  }

  returnUpdatePostListener() {
    return this.updatePosts.asObservable();
  }

  addPost(title: string, content: string) {
    const post: Post = {
      title: title,
      content: content
    }
    this.posts.push(post);
    this.updatePosts.next([...this.posts]);
  }
}
```

post-list.component.ts:

```
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(public postService: PostService) { }
  posts: Post[] = [];
  postsSub!: Subscription;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.posts = this.postService.getPosts();
    this.postsSub = this.postService.returnUpdatePostListener().subscribe(
      (posts: Post[]) => this.posts = posts
    )
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.postsSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

post-list-component.html:

```
<div id="accordion-collapse" data-accordion="collapse">
  <div *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index">
    <h2 attr.id="accordion-collapse-heading-{{i}}">
      <button type="button" [ngClass]="i === 0 ? 'rounded-t-xl':'rounded-none'"
        class="flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 font-medium rtl:text-right text-gray-500 border border-b-0 border-gray-200 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 gap-3"
        attr.data-accordion-target="#accordion-collapse-body-{{i}}" aria-expanded="false"
        attr.aria-controls="accordion-collapse-body-{{i}}">
        <span>{{post.title}} </span>
        <svg data-accordion-icon class="w-3 h-3 rotate-180 shrink-0" aria-hidden="true"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 10 6">
          <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
            d="M9 5 5 1 1 5" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div attr.id="accordion-collapse-body-{{i}}" class="hidden" attr.aria-labelledby="accordion-collapse-heading-{{i}}">
      <div class="p-5 border border-b-0 border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-900">
        <p class="mb-2 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">{{post.content}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Console Log of Posts]

[image: Binding Error]

Comment: What is the current issue ? Your "posts" are not rendered in the DOM or your accordion is not expanding correctly ?

Comment: The issue is the posts are showing but the accordion is not expanding at all. It cannot be expanded, it only expands with a static array of “posts”.

Comment: Could you please create the StackBlitz URL in order to assist better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `initFlowbite` again after rendering the new data seems to work:

```js
@Component(...)
export class App {
  posts: Post[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    initFlowbite();
  }

  add() {
    this.posts = this.posts.concat({
      title: 'article ' + this.posts.length,
      content: 'some content',
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      initFlowbite();
    });
  }
}
```

In this example I'm using `setTimeout` so that Angular can finish rendering before feeding the new markup to Flowbite.

[Working example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zz1idn?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

This solution feels a bit hackish. You may want to consider something like https://flowbite-angular.com/accordion or use `[ngClass]` without Flowbite like Q.Rey suggested.

Comment: Thank you so much Rens, your solution worked and thanks for the other resource suggestion. You're the best.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce your example but i'm not getting how you could possibly change your accordion body visibility without any logic code.

So i made an example using `[ngClass]` to show/hide your accordion body:

For this, we got an integer array containing your expanded accordion index working a method to store or delete your desired panel.

```
  openedPosts: Set = new Set([]);

  togglePost(index: number) {
  if (this.openedPosts.has(index)) {
   const toDeleteIndex = [...this.openedPosts].find((obj) => obj === index);
   this.openedPosts.delete(toDeleteIndex);
  } else {
   this.openedPosts.add(index);
}
```

}

and then in your template we can manage each accordion body visibility like this

```
 [ngClass]="openedPosts.has(i) ? 'block' : 'hidden'"
```

See the real example below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pzmdfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: thanks for your input! Really appreciate it but I am still puzzled why it would not work with a dynamic array, maybe I will look into using other components besides the Accordion. Thanks again!

Comment: Be careful calling `openedPosts.includes` in your template like this, as it can negatively impact the performance of your application: it will iterate over your array every time when Angular change detection runs. In this example the effect is probably negligible, but it's just as easy to use a `Set` for `openedPosts` here and call `openedPosts.has`, which performs better.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i changed the sample with your preconized usage of a Set